# How can I configure my global error handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

I have my custom error class:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
namespace Services.Errors.Exceptions;

public class HttpResponseException : Exception
{
public int StatusCode { get; private set; }

public HttpResponseException(int statusCode , string message) : base(message)
    {
    StatusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

Also I have an error handler:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Services.Contracts;
using Services.Errors.Exceptions;
using JsonSerializer = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer;

namespace Services.Errors.Handler;

public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException httpResponseMessage)
        {
            var error = new ErrorDto()
            {
                Code = httpResponseMessage.StatusCode,
                Description = context.Exception.Message
            };

            context.Result = new JsonResult(error) { StatusCode =  (int)httpResponseMessage.StatusCode};
        }
    }
}
```

I register my handler in the Program.cs class which should return a response to the controller:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
});
```

I have a problem. When I throw my custom exception for example in a controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Host.Core.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Sentry;
using Services.Abstractions;
using Services.Contracts;
using Services.Errors.Exceptions;

namespace Host.Core.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CheckController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ILogger<CheckController> _logger;
        private IServiceIntegration _service;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public CheckController(ILogger<CheckController> logger, IServiceIntegration service, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _service = service;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Client(TransactionModel trnModel)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(404, "NotFound");
        }
    }
}
```

it returns the response I expect:

```
{
  "code": 404,
  "description": "NotFound"
}
```

but when I get a 404 error when sending a request and I throw my exception, then the normal error from the class is returned to me Exception():

```
System.Exception: Services.Errors.Exceptions.HttpResponseException: NotFound
```

Comment: It's a difference if a route can be matched but its handler throws a 404 ( then it gets caught in your middleware) or if no route can be matched. How did you produce the latter exception?

Comment: BTW: I'd consider this an abuse of Exceptions. A thing not being found is not an exceptional use case.